# Flutter retrofit null is not subtype of string

Tags: flutter, retrofit

[Code Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVmql.png)

i want to set some fields dynamic, but i got error like this 'null is not subtype of type 'string''. How can i fix it?

Is it possible to send null data together File?

Comment: We don't debug images

Answer (score 0):

One of your fields is getting a null value but its type is not nullable.